# Docker Images Report as Taking 5-10x Actual Space on BTRFS Filesystem

Tags: docker

Today's day one with Docker, and I've been overjoyed (cough) to find that docker is taking **5-10 times as much space to store the images on my hard drive as the images themselves.** A visual inspection in baobab shows very similar (though not perfectly identical) folder structure repeated among the five subfolders of /var/lib/docker.

A 1.8G docker image takes 18G on my disk. If I rebuild the images from scratch using the same sources, Docker barely increases disk storage, plus 1G give or take--so at least it's deduplicating sources in that sense. Once I remove the images storage goes down to 400K.

I thought maybe there were a bunch of different sources that had to be differentially compared to get to the final version of the image I had downloaded earlier, so I downloaded the 18.04 Ubuntu image (79M) next to verify if that was the case, but even so, baobab is back to showing 401 MB under /var/lib/docker/. What the heck?!? Am I missing something, or is Docker being dreadfully inefficient? Is there an evil BTRFS compression kernel bug? Does Docker hate disk encryption? Please tell me Docker doesn't just laugh in your face and fill up your hard drive instead of anti-de-duplicating your data.

---

*On a clean install of x11vnc/docker-desktop with nothing else*

```
user@Ubuntu ~ $ docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              1                   0                   1.817GB             1.817GB (100%)
Containers          0                   0                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       2                   0                   72.87kB             72.87kB (100%)
Build Cache                                                 0B                  0B
```

[image: Docker Size]

Comment: What does `docker system df` say?

Comment: @dpwrussell - 1.8G. See edit for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Docker on Btrfs uses a lot of snapshots. Btrfs snapshots use copy on write so that when they're changed, only the changed parts use new disk space.

But regular disk tools don't know about snapshots and count the space as a full copy for each snapshot.

Use `btrfs fi du -s /var/lib/docker` to use the Btrfs tools to measure it.

Comment: Terminal complains that `du` is an unknown token on my system. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with btrfs-tools installed

Comment: Accorrding to comment #2 on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436585/get-size-of-btrfs-directory-which-may-contain-subvolumes), `du` doesn't work because my OS has an old version of `btrfs-progs` installed. To update `btrfs-progs` I followed [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-build-and-install-the-latest-version-of-btrfs-tools-on-linux/). I installed the apt dependencies listed + python3.5-dev, did clone/git/make/upgrade for [Facebook's zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) and also for `btrfs-progs`. The `btrfs fi du...` command works but still says 8GiB.

Comment: @BrandonLebedev: Add the exclusive and set shared values together. That's how much actual space is being used.

Comment: Despite a 30% reporting discrepancy between what `docker system df` and `btrfs fi du...` reports (when adding the exclusive and shared values), this answers my question. If you can edit it into the answer and message me I'll accept it as the answer.